# throttle/limit a logged in user's http requests to specific page on a per day basis

Tags: users, htaccess, user-access, authentication, http

I have a resource on my WordPress page that I only want to show X times per day per logged in user. I'm using the twenty sixteen WordPress theme.

Currently, Guests / visitors / non logged in users are forced via redirects to authenticate to my site in order to access any content.

How do impose a http request limit / pageview limit on a per-logged-in-user per day or per hour basis? I don't want to do it by IP address, I want to do it by unique user.

Has anyone seen this done? The closet I've seen is : https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/technical-question-how-to-limit-the-number-of-page-views-for-a-specific-site-under-a-wpmu-instsall#post-384060 but is there a solution already for this? I've searched for throttle, page view, http , limit, restrict, expire, but nothing seems to be restricting content on a logged-in-user-per-day-basis.

Thank you

**UPDATE: I am overriding the default page.php file of twenty sixteen theme to implement basic page-view limiting for logged-in users. **

```
   <?php
```

//First, check for get_current_user_id.

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
    // Logged out
}   else {
        // Logged in.

```
    //Then create a log of visits by adding information to a user's metadata with update_user_meta & get_user_meta. 

    $COUNT_VISITS_TOTAL_LIMIT = 20;
    $countVisitsUsed = 0;

    if (get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'countVisitsUsed', true)) {
        $countVisitsUsed = get_user_meta($current_user->ID,'countVisitsUsed',true);
        update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'countVisitsUsed', $countVisitsUsed+1); //increment
    }else{
          update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'countVisitsUsed', 1, false );
          $countVisitsUsed = get_user_meta($current_user->ID,'countVisitsUsed',true);
    }


    if ($countVisitsUsed == null || $countVisitsUsed ==false || $countVisitsUsed < $COUNT_VISITS_TOTAL_LIMIT) { //allow page load



        //start of page.php

            /**
             * The template for displaying pages
             *
             * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
             * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages and that
             * other "pages" on your WordPress site will use a different template.
             *
             * @package WordPress
             * @subpackage Twenty_Sixteen
             * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
             */

            get_header(); ?>
            <div id="primary" class="content-area">
                <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
                    <?php
                    // Start the loop.
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                        // Include the page content template.
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

                        // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                        if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                            comments_template();
                        }

                        // End of the loop.
                    endwhile;
                    ?>

                </main><!-- .site-main -->

                <?php get_sidebar( 'content-bottom' ); ?>

            </div><!-- .content-area -->

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
            <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Give 'em some cookies. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check for [`get_current_user_id`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/). Then create a log of visits by adding information to a user's metadata with [`update_user_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) & [`get_user_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta).

On every page hit that you care about you can run a function to determine rate/limit of usage per user.

If they break the rules, you can redirect to a page that doesn't contain that logic with [`wp_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/).

Comment: With Jgraup's advice, I overrode my page.php file with an attempted solution.  It compiles, but I have coded it incorrectly. My expectation is that a logged-in user visits a wordpress page and we count this activity by incrementing a variable in wp_usermeta. For some reason, my attempted solution and testing process do not yield any "countVisitsUsed" field in the wp_usermeta table.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: @pdro Defining the maximum counts as a variable but then referencing it as a constant in your conditional might have something to do with it ;-)

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook thank you. It is working.